# Adding a button to JavaScript link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a web page using JavaScript, Java Spring MVC and CSS html. I am very new to this type of coding so would really appreciate any help. Basically I want to replace the hyperlink with that says "..." with a button that says "back". When the user searches in the input box a list of results comes up below. The "..." link brings them back one step and this is what  I 
want to replace with a button.

Here is my code:

```
display=display+"<a href='javascript:exploreThis(\" "+content.pathParent+"\")'>...</a>";
display=display+"<br>";
```

HTML:

```
<form name="formExplorer" id="formExplorerId" submit="listPath()">
Path: <br /> <input type="text" name="path" id="explorerPathId">
<button onclick="undoLine(counter)"> Yes</button>                       
</form>
<div id="explorerContentAreaId"></div>
```

If any more information is required please let me know.

Comment: can you show us your html please

Comment: I have added it now @לבנימלכה

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: do you mean instead `Yes` will be `Back`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`style.display`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp) to hide(means `none`) or show (means `inline-block` or `block`)

```js
function changeToBack(){
 document.getElementsByClassName("search")[0].style.display="none";
 document.getElementsByClassName("back")[0].style.display="inline-block";
}
```

```css
.back{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<a class="search" onclick="changeToBack()" href="#">click me to see back</a>
<a href="#" class="back">back</a>
```

**EDIT to your code added:**

```js
function undoLine(counter){
 document.getElementsByClassName("yes")[0].style.display="none";
 document.getElementsByClassName("back")[0].style.display="inline-block";
}
```

```css
.back{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<form name="formExplorer" id="formExplorerId" submit="listPath()">
Path: <br /> <input type="text" name="path" id="explorerPathId">
<button class="yes" onclick="undoLine('counter')" type="button"> Yes</button>  
<button class="back" type="button"> Back</button>  
</form>
<div id="explorerContentAreaId"></div>
```